# How do I have the system start a process on xrdp connect and kill it on xrdp disconnect

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, ffmpeg

I would like to start a background process defined in a shell script when an xrdp connection to an instance running on AWS EC2 is instantiated.

There's a subtle difference between having the process start on system start or user login or something of the sort, because I don't want to start the process, *unless* there's an *active xrdp connection* that has been instantiated.

Upon the user disconnecting from an xrdp connection, I would like to have the process to stop running in the background, following a certain set of preconditions of "completion".

The example use case I am working on is to start ffmpeg to record the xrdp session, have the recorded session be uploaded to AWS S3, deleted off the instance, and then end the background process in the background.